# How can I make CSS grid items have auto height using tailwind?

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css

Let's suppose I have this 2 by 2 grid layout made with the help of **[Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/)**:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inline-grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2">
  <div class="px-1">Full name:</div>
  <div class="px-1">Favoutite fruits:</div>
  <div class="px-1">John Doe</div>
  <div class="px-1">
    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Oranges</li>
      <li>Bananas</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the above layout is that the rows are equal in height or, in other words, all the grid items are forced to have *the height of the tallest of them*.

The items on the first row must have the height required by only a single row of text.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply remove `grid-rows-2`. No need to define the rows, defining the columns is enough

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inline-grid grid-cols-2">
  <div class="px-1">Full name:</div>
  <div class="px-1">Favoutite fruits:</div>
  <div class="px-1">John Doe</div>
  <div class="px-1">
    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Oranges</li>
      <li>Bananas</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why adding a row definition sets a height? and is it posible to modify?

Comment: @GerardoBuenrostroGonzález that's how Tailwind is defined. grid-rows-2 set 2 equal height and the height is defined by the tallest one `repeat(2;minmax(0,1fr))`

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: Ok, that work but I would like to says that the virtual cursor of a blind person will read informations as they come in the dom. So if it reads the Full name, the person who is blind will understand that the guy's name is "favorite fruits". Building a grid row instead would solve this because we would have Full name, then John Doe, favorite fruits and the list of fruits. It make sense if we want to make a correct document with a reliable use of html elements. Thanks for the trick anyways.